# API won't stop eager loading

Tags: doctrine, api-platform.com

I'm reading the docs here:
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/performance/#eager-loading

No matter what config I try, my API always eager loads relations in my payload.
Why is the API Platform ignoring these settings?

I've tried this to no avail

```
# api/config/packages/api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    eager_loading:
        force_eager: false

# also tried this
api_platform:
    eager_loading:
        enabled: false
```

I've also tried annotations on my entity & relationship

````
/**
 * @ApiResource(attributes={"force_eager"=false})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
  /**
     * @var Address
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address", fetch="LAZY")
     */
    public $address;```
````

Comment: I have the [opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56169719/how-to-get-api-platform-to-load-related-e-g-many2one-resources-entities) problem. I wish we could trade.

Comment: @jim can you provide a query path that was taken for your request? Or rather how did you determine eager loading is used as opposed to lazy loading? For clarification `eager` and `lazy` operate similarly, where `eager` retrieves the associations immediately, `lazy` loads them when first accessed, by first loading them as uninitialized and only containing the id..This results in almost identical results. The api-platform normalizer accounts for uninitialized objects.