# How to get API-Platform to load related (e.g. Many2One) resources/entities?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

According to the [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/v2.1/core/performance/#eager-loading), api-platform will eager-load related resources by default.

But on the default configuration, all my queries to resources with relations (mostly with typical `Many2One` relationships) populate these  properties with the object IRI instead of the serialized object.

E.g., for this entity:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BoostLeadContactActionRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="BoostLeadContactActions")
 */
class BoostLeadContactAction {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\BoostLead", inversedBy="contacts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $boostLead;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ContactChannel", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, referencedColumnName="Id")
     */
    private $channel;

    // getters/setters/extra properties removed for brevity
}
```

Then we have the corresponding `ContactChannel`:

```php
/**
 * ContactChannel
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ContactChannels")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ContactChannel {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Id", type="smallint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Name", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name = '';
}
```

I've set up  `fetch="EAGER"` on the relationship even if in theory is not needed. My configuration is the default, but just in case I actually wrote this in my `api_platform.yaml`:

```
    eager_loading:
        # To enable or disable eager loading.
        enabled: true

        # Fetch only partial data according to serialization groups.
        # If enabled, Doctrine ORM entities will not work as expected if any of the other fields are used.
        fetch_partial: false

        # Max number of joined relations before EagerLoading throws a RuntimeException.
        max_joins: 30

        # Force join on every relation.
        # If disabled, it will only join relations having the EAGER fetch mode.
        force_eager: true
```

The result of `debug:config api_platform` confirms the correct configuration is applied:

```
Current configuration for extension with alias "api_platform"
=============================================================

api_platform:
    title: FooBar API
    description: 'FooBar API, only for authenticated use'
    version: 0.8.0
    name_converter: null
    path_segment_name_generator: api_platform.path_segment_name_generator.underscore
    eager_loading:
        enabled: true
        fetch_partial: false
        max_joins: 30
        force_eager: true
```

And yet the results will be something like:

```
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/BoostLeadContactAction",
  "@id": "/api/boost_lead_contact_actions/9",
  "@type": "BoostLeadContactAction",
  "id": 9,
  "boostLead": "/api/boost_leads/30",
  "channel": "/api/contact_channels/1",
  "direction": "outgoing",
  "successful": true,
  "type": "/api/lead_contact_attempt_reasons/1",
  "notes": "2",
  "createdAt": "2019-05-16T10:27:33+00:00",
  "updatedAt": "2019-05-16T10:27:33+00:00"
}
```

"boostLead", "channel" and "type" should be actual entities, eagerly loaded, but only IRIs are returned instead. I confirmed that the SQL query performed does not include any kind of `join`.

Funnily enough, it seems to be the opposite trouble than [this other user is having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55985251/api-wont-stop-eager-loading). I wish I had their problems.

What could be preventing these relationships to be loaded eagerly? The relationships work otherwise (I can do other queries with Doctrine, or create custom serialization groups and the related properties will be included).

Comment: It's not every day that I find a developer asking to have the problem of another. (I'm searching a solution and come back)

Comment: Did you try to add `@ApiProperty(attributes={"fetchEager": true})` the line above `private $channel;` ?

Comment: Did you tru to add `* @ApiResource(attributes={"force_eager"=true})`, the lines above each class declaration?

Comment: Tried both. Didn't work. But as you see `force_eager` is enabled at global level, re-enabling it at resource or property level shouldn't make a difference. Tried it nonetheless, to no effect.

Comment: As the question states, you should not have to do anything by default for eager loading.  This is just a pure guess but try commenting out the enabled,fetch_partial and max_joins under eager_loading so your config matches the docs.  The fetch_partial in particular may be causing issues.  Might also help to start a fresh project with maybe two joined entities and nothing else.

Comment: I'll try, @Cerad. But those are the default settings nontheless. I've just put them in my configuration because of growing desperation.

Comment: Do you purge and warmup your cache each time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default [dereferenceable IRIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier) are used to display the related associations.
Looking at the executed statements you should not see an explicit `JOIN` query but rather additional `SELECT` statements for the related associations.

If you are wanting the JSON representation of the associated object.
You need to specify the `Serialization` `@Groups` for the desired properties in the related association.
This will cause the `SELECT` statement to add in a `JOIN` to retrieve the related data to be serialized.

For more details see https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#embedding-relations

```
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(normalizationContext={ "groups": {"boost"} })
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="BoostLeadContactActions")
 */
class BoostLeadContactAction {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"boost"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\BoostLead", inversedBy="contacts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"boost"})
     */
    private $boostLead;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ContactChannel", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, referencedColumnName="Id")
     * @Groups({"boost"})
     */
    private $channel;

    // getters/setters/extra properties removed for brevity
}
```

```
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Table(name="ContactChannels")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ContactChannel {

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="Id", type="smallint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @Groups({"boost"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="Name", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"boost"})
     */
    private $name = '';
}
```

Which should result in the normalized values being retrieved

```
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/BoostLeadContactAction",
  "@id": "/api/boost_lead_contact_actions/9",
  "@type": "BoostLeadContactAction",
  "id": 9,
  "boostLead": "/api/boost_leads/30",
  "channel": {
      "@id": "/api/contact_channels/1",
      "@type": "ContactChannel",
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Test"
   },
  "direction": "outgoing",
  "successful": true,
  "type": "/api/lead_contact_attempt_reasons/1",
  "notes": "2",
  "createdAt": "2019-05-16T10:27:33+00:00",
  "updatedAt": "2019-05-16T10:27:33+00:00"
}
```

Comment: Mmmh. I had misread the documentation. I interpreted the "default EAGER" as that relationships were embedded automatically. This other part of the documentation makes obvious that's not the case. I guess it's not possible to mark a whole entity as belonging to a serialization group?

Comment: Not to knowledge, since the context can be changed and other implications doing so would cause.